# Assign variable with variable in function

Tags: python, function

Let's say we have

```
def Foo(Bar=0,Song=0):  
    print(Bar)
    print(Song)
```

And I want to assign any one of the two parameters in the function with the variable sing and SongVal:

```
Sing = Song
SongVal = 2
```

So that it can be run like:
`Foo(Sing=SongVal)`
Where Sing would assign the Song parameter to the SongVal which is 2.
The result should be printed like so:

```
0
2
```

So should I rewrite my function or is it possible to do it the way I want to? (With the code above you get an error saying Foo has no parameter Sing. Which I understand why, any way to overcome this without rewriting the function too much?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is the `**kwargs` way of passing arbitrary keyword arguments:

```
kwargs = {Sing: SongVal}
foo(**kwargs)
```

See section [4.7 of the tutorial at www.python.org](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments) for more examples.

Comment: Worked, thanks!
Only things that needed changing was Sing should equal a string Sing = "Song"